# File transfer between app and media server

Tags: python, django

I have a multi-server setup, with two boxes serving dynamic requests through Django, and a static/media file server, serving with NginX.

My question is: what is the recommended way of transfering uploaded media files from the django boxes to the media server?

The main issue is the files uploaded through the admin. All user generated content is put in a celery queue, which pulls the files over using sftp, and resizes them. The files uploaded in the admin however, should be processed in the request so that they are ready when the content is changed.

I have tried two options:

- Using the sftp backend of django-storages. This gives me errors from the underlying paramiko.
- Using an NFS mount, which gave me a lot of head-aches with permissions.

So what is the recommended way? Or how do other people do this? SFTP, SCP, SSHFS, NFS, CIFS, WebDav, etc?

Comment: Care to elaborate on how I accomplish what I want with rsync? Having a cronjob rsync a folder every minute doesn't suffice, as this may show admin posts with a failing image for a minute or more (the images have to be resized after transfer as well).

Answer (score 1):

Are your file uploads related to any models? If so, set the storage media to your media server, and when you create/save the object defined in your models.py that has a FileField using the uploaded file, it will automatically save it to the specified storage media. Here are the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class

Comment: Yes, I know. That is what I am using. The point is that the transfer method (sftp) is not reliably working. So I was wondering what people use in this case.